# How do I load SoundCloud JS SDK for Streaming correctly?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I scoured the site for hints that might answer this for me.  This might be SoundCloud-specific, or this might be just a JS newbie question.  I searched StackOverflow to the best of my ability trying to resolve this myself, but I'm pretty well stumped.  I'm sure it's something obvious and easy to someone with more experience than me.

I'm trying to build a test webpage that uses SoundCloud's JS API for streaming tracks without using their player UI.  I looked at their docs, found their example (here: http://connect.soundcloud.com/examples/streaming.html), and tried to make it work with a track and my Client ID, but to no avail.

Here's my basic HTML page, based on the example linked above:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
    <script>
      SC.initialize({
       client_id: "MY_CLIENT_ID"
     });

      $("#stream").live("click", function(){
        SC.stream("/tracks/47101735", {autoPlay: true});
      });
    </script>

    <input type="button" href="#" id="stream" value="Stream It Again, Sam" />
</body>
</html>
```

In my browser's error console, when I load this page, I get the error: **ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $**.  Thinking back to all I know about JS and web programming (which is almost nothing), I figured the SoundCloud SDK wasn't getting loaded.  I tried a number of things to get the path to the 'sdk.js' file to resolve, like adding an http:// absolute path to their hosted JS file or pointing it at a local copy of the SDK.  Didn't seem to make a difference.

Anyone have a hint or a solution for me?  Syntax for a better search to an existing answer I may not have found?  Thanks very much.

Comment: .live is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 - you do need to reference the jQuery library as mentioned by someone below.  Try .on

Answer (score 3):

The sdk.js file is getting downloaded succesfully..

$ represents jquery object there.. so , we need to include jquery.js as well..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some Page</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script>
  SC.initialize({
   client_id: "MY_CLIENT_ID"
 });

  $("#stream").live("click", function(){
    SC.stream("/tracks/47101735", {autoPlay: true});
  });
</script>

<input type="button" href="#" id="stream" value="Stream It Again, Sam" />
```